# Casting to non base class but with common ancestors

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

Let's say we have the following classes:

```
class A
{
public:
   A() {}

};

class B
{
public:
   B() {}
   virtual ~B() {}
};

template<typename T>
class BB: public B
{
public:
    BB() {}
};

class C: public A, public BB<bool>
{
public:
    C() {}
};

class D: public A, public B
{
public:
    D() {}
};
```

Do casting a `C` object to class type `D` is possible/allowed/safe ? This in order to access non templated stuff and use polymorphism.

I tried and got the error `no matching function for call to 'D::D(C&)'`.

Do adding the constructor `D::D(C& c): A(c), B(c) {}` will suffice to do so ?

Please note that I am currently using **C++11** and I must stick to it, thus I need a compatible solution, however there may be better solutions with later standards so you may still share those for the sake of my knowledge.

**Edit**: after reading the comments, here are some further explaination to my problem

The definition of `B` and `BB` cannot be changed, see it like classes from an API that can't modified.

Casting directly is calling the constructor and creates an new object, that's not what I want, thus it requires *Indirection* as mentionned in the answers.

Given this other class:

```
class Cbis: public A, public BB<float>
{
public:
    Cbis() {}
};
```

The only purpose of the class `D` would be to allow to store `C` and `Cbis` references in the same container and be able to access methods from both `A` and `B` classes.

In the end, it may not be possible at all as, even with common ancestors, as `D` is not a base class.

Therefore, what could be the alternatives ? Besides storing in two separate containers one based on `A` pointers and the on `B` pointers.

Comment: If you instantiated it as a `C` you cant expect it to be of type `D`, thus not a valid casting.

Comment: @Neijwiert I would go even further. It is not like you can't expect an instance of `C` to be also an instance of `D`, because this would imply that it might be one, but you can't know for sure. An instance of `C` just isn't an instance of `D`.

Comment: If you intention is to create new **values**, and not use pointers or references, then polymorphism has little to do with it. You are on to the right approach, as far as the little details you've given go.

Comment: I thought this was a good question - `C` is an A, and `C` is a `BB`, also `D` is an `A`, and `D` is a `B`, and finally a `BB` is a `B`. But all this still does not imply `C` is a `D`! Also, I suggest first compiling  and seeing what the compiler says.

Comment: Also following what @JeromeReinländer, you could simplify this greatly with `A` and `B` inheriting from `C` (only, no more classes) for example. `A` still cannot be converted to a `B` or vice versa.

Comment: OP should try to think of added member variables to class `D` which aren't present in `C` and then think of what should happen if casting were valid.

Comment: @Neijwiert I edited my question to clarify the behavior I am looking for

Answer (score 4):

> Do casting a C object to class type D is possible/allowed/safe ? This in order to access non templated stuff and use polymorphism.

*Indirection* is required to gain runtime polymorphism.

If the `C` object is *referred indirectly*, then you can `dynamic_cast` the reference (or pointer) to a `D` reference (pointer) since they have common ancestors (that have virtual functions). The cast succeeds if and only if that `C` object is a base of a derived class that also inherits `D`. `dynamic_cast` will safely fail if this is not the case.

> Do adding the constructor `D::D(C& c): A(c), B(c) {}` will suffice to do so ?

Adding a converting constructor will make the type (implicitly if the constructor isn't `explicit`) convertible to another. With such constructor the conversion can be done explicitly using `static_cast`. It is important to understand that the result of the conversion (from `C` to `D`) is no longer a `C` object.

Comment: However type information needs to be enabled when building the program so that dynamic_cast can be used, since it is not bound to be enabled if one were to use C++11. Great answer though.

Comment: For out-of-the-box C++11, type information enabled is presumed.

Comment: @user2079303 I edited my question to clarify the behavior I am looking for, your answer confirm what I thought but I am still looking for the best alternative

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), [link.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70de9ebf59bb7c97)

Safe? Not at all! reinterpret_cast tells the compiler to ignore everything and simply treat object pointer by Obj2 as an object of C, it worked in this example because the byte happened to be aligned, simply changing the order of functions or adding others will cause it to crash.

Comment: Maybe mention that it is `undefined behaviour`

Comment: Why even mention reinterpret_cast? I'm serious, it's like giving someone a loaded gun and saying *"This isn't safe, but have fun"*.

Comment: @StoryTeller I agree, but it might help OP to understand the terminology  used with these situations.

Comment: That's always good to be reminded that, indeed `reinterpret_cast` appears be too dangerous, unless I can guarantee the byte ordering ?

Comment: Yes, the bytes have to be same; it has its uses though in normal OOP it's almost always a mistake. Say you have a message queue and are passing structs, with first few bytes header, then body, then you can always read the header and reinterpret_cast to whatever struct it is. Stuff like that.